# scala Ide custom setter error

Tags: scala

I am testing a simple scala program how to do custom setter.
    but it is giving me compile time error.

```
class Duck1 {
     private var privateAge = 10
     def age() = privateAge
     def age_ = (value : Int) { if(value > privateAge) privateAge = value}
}

object CustomGetter extends App {
    val f = new Duck1
    //f.age = 20
    println(f.age)
}
```

The line `def age_ = (value : Int) { if(value > privateAge) privateAge = value}`
is giving error.

Comment: When you have errors you should include the exact error text along with the line that is causing it.  Seeing the error makes it much easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Even if possible/syntaxically ok, using mutability in such trivial case is not the part Scala usual practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
def age_= (value : Int): Unit = { if(value > privateAge) privateAge = value}
```

The method name should be `age_` and there was a `=` missing after the signature.

You also have to omit the brackets in `def age() = privateAge`

Finally, I agree with the comments. You should include the error message in your question.